# Vk Api. Код не выполняется после бесконечного цикла while True

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, циклы, вконтакте

Бот не хочет работать в двух (и более) беседах одновременно. Когда его исключаешь из первой он начинает работать во второй. Я так понял проблема в бесконечном цикле while True, код просто не выполняется после него. Как мне его по умному и во время остановить? По идее цикл спама и должен быть бесконечным.

```
def write_msg(chat_id, random_id, message):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': chat_id, "random_id" : random_id, "message" : message})

def write_stick_msg(chat_id, random_id, sticker_id):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': chat_id, "random_id" : random_id, "sticker_id" : sticker_id})

while True:
    try:
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat:
                print("Ok")
                event_text = event.object.text.lower()
                if event_text == "[club190004487|церковь картошки], помощь":
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, "Вы вызвали помощь, доступные команды:\n1. Служба\n2. Смайлики\n3. Стикеры\n4...в разработке")
                elif event_text == "[club190004487|церковь картошки], служба":
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, "Атеисту *** полбу! КАРТОШКИ СОБИРАЕМСЯ!!!\n*спам машина запускается*")
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, "3")
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, "2")
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, "1")
                    while True:
                        write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, spam_molitva)
                        write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, spam_song)
                        write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, spam_molitva)
                        write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, "Картошка БОГ")
                        write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, "Картошка БОГ")
                        write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, "Картошка БОГ")
                elif event_text == "[club190004487|церковь картошки], смайлики":
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, """Атеисту *** полбу! КАРТОШКИ СОБИРАЕМСЯ!!!\n*щас будет *** смайликов*""")
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, "3")
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, "2")
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, "1")
                    while True:
                        write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, spam_emoji)
                elif event_text == "[club190004487|церковь картошки], стикеры": 
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, """Атеисту *** полбу! КАРТОШКИ СОБИРАЕМСЯ!!!\n*щас будет *** стикеров*""")
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, "3")
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, "2")
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, "1")
                    while True:
                        write_stick_msg(event.chat_id, event.object.random_id, str(random.randint(7674, 7721)))
    except Exception as read_timeout:
        continue
    except Exception as permission_denied:
        break
```

Comment: Вполне логично, что код после бесконечного цикла не выполняется. Но это происходит даже раньше: `for event in longpoll.listen()`. Если Вы хотите запустить бота для двух бесед, запускайте отдельно или используйте модули `threading`, `multiprocessing`, создавая отдельный процесс/поток для прослушки событий.

Answer (score 0):

Например чтобы отправить сообщение просто сформируйте словарь:

```
def write_aud_msg_chat(chat_id, attachment):
    return vk.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': chat_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': 0})
```

```
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
group = '123456789'
wait = 25
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, group, wait)
for event in longpoll.listen():
```

Если же вы хотите авторизоваться с помощью пользователя просто укажите его токен (чтобы его получить перейдите по ссылке и скопируйте из адресной строки то что после acces_token= и до &: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=2685278&scope=1073737727&redirect_uri=https://api.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&response_type=token&revoke=1 ):

```
vk1 = vk_api.VkApi(token=token1)
```

```
    peer_id = event.object.peer_id
    chat_id = peer_id - 2000000000
    user = event.object.from_id
    mess = event.object.text.lower()
```

Сам код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
def write_msg_chat(chat_id, message):
    return vk.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': chat_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': 0})

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
group = '123456789'
wait = 25
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, group, wait)
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        peer_id = event.object.peer_id
        chat_id = peer_id - 2000000000
        user = event.object.from_id
        mess = event.object.text.lower()
        #тут реакция на различные команды
```

Не забудте добавить НУЖНЫЕ импорты:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
```

И самое главное НЕ используйте цикл While просто избавьтесь от него